# Why does this LinkedList addLast implementation work?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am working on adding an item to the end of a linked list (this isn't homework...just an exercise for myself).

Here is the program:

```
public class CustomLinkedList {

    private static Node head = null;
    private int size = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomLinkedList myList = new CustomLinkedList();
        myList.add(5);
        myList.add(9);
        myList.add(3);

        System.out.println("List Size: " + myList.size);
        myList.print();
    }

    private int size() {
        return this.size;
    }

    private void print() {
            Node temp = head;
           for (int i=0; i<=size-1;i++){
                System.out.print(temp.value + " ");
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void add(int value) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node();
            head.value = value;
            head.next = null;
            size++;
        } else {
            Node temp = head;
            while (temp.next != null) {
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            temp.next = new Node();
            (temp.next).value = value;
            size++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Node class:

```
public class Node {
    public int value;
    public Node next;

    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

**Here is what I think is happening:**
1. I have an original/ongoing list starting with "head." 
2. I want to add to that list.
3. To add to it, I need to find the end of it. I do that by creating a new node called temp (which is just a copy of the original list). 
4. I traverse the copy (temp) until I reached the end.
5. Once I reach the end, I create a new node.

To me, this is where my code stops. Now, in my mind, I need to add code that says, "Alright, you have your new node, you know where it needs to go, so lets go through the real list and add it."

But I don't have that. According to my debugger (image below), the right thing is happening, but I don't see the magic that is adding the new node to the original list. How is this working?

[image]

**Edit:** 
I did look at other implementations (like the one [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/code/LinkedList.java)); it looked very similar. However, I still couldn't find why it works without assigning temp to head (or to head.next). I get Linked Lists in theory I believe. I just don't understand why this bit works.

Comment: What line "head = temp"? The code is fine and makes sense, although it could be significantly reduced and refactored.

Comment: In addition to @Bohemian  Given C++ code is adding values reverse order against to your JAVA code.

Comment: @Bohemian I tried editing my question. I described what I thought was going on in my code versus what is happening. Hopefully, that makes my question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is that `temp` is *different* to `head`. It's not.

They are both variables holding *references* to the *same* `Node` object. Changes made via either variable are reflected in the (same) object they reference. When you add a `Node` to `temp`, you add it to the *real* list.

Comment: Thanks! That's fair and makes sense for the most part. But how is that different from this: let's say I have int x = 5, and I say int y = x. Then if x changes, y changes. However, if y changes, that doesn't mean that x changes. So, to me that's like saying, Node temp = head, if head changes, temp changes, but if temp changes, head doesn't necessarily change.

Comment: Now that I think about it, that logic may not hold up because I'm comparing primitive types to objects...